# How to send email in Java from Xpages?

Tags: java, xpages, html-email

In my Xpages application I want to send (HTML) email from Java. I found this nice EmailBean code as snippet on OpenNTF:

https://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter

I converted the code to an common Email class and not use it as a managed bean.

I also want to use the code in a different way: instead of working with a DominoDocument that is created from a XPage I want to use the class straight from anotehr java class. However I face the following problems:

The code expects a DominoDocument and a field on that document for the content of the email message.

So in my sendMail method I tried:

```
Database db = DominoUtils.getCurrentDatabase();
DominoDocument fakeMail = (DominoDocument) db.createDocument();
```

But this DominoDocument is never created (the code breaks here)

```
Database db = DominoUtils.getCurrentDatabase();
Document fakeMail = db.createDocument();
```

works fine but

```
Email email = new Email();
email.setDocument(fakeMail);
```

complains that a DominoDocument is expected and a Document is not excepted.

My next thoughts where to skip the creation of a intermediate Document but when I tried

```
email.setBodyHTML("Hello World");
```

I get the following message in the console:

[1728:0016-08FC] 2018-09-15 16:18:14   HTTP JVM: Method setBodyHTML(string) is not permitted

Is there anyone who can guide me how I can change this email class so I do not need a DominoDocument? Actually I do not need a Document at all. I could set the properties for the email object myself if the setBodyHTML() would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not strip down that email class?

```
package com.ibm.xsp.utils;

/**
 * @author Tony McGuckin, IBM
 */

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Document;
import lotus.domino.MIMEEntity;
import lotus.domino.MIMEHeader;
import lotus.domino.NotesException;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.Stream;

import com.ibm.domino.xsp.module.nsf.NotesContext;

public class Email {

    private ArrayList<String> sendTo;
      private ArrayList<String> ccList;
      private ArrayList<String> bccList;
      private String senderEmail;
      private String senderName;
      private String subject;
      private String fieldName;
      private String bannerHTML;
      private String bodyHTML;
      private String footerHTML;

      private boolean debugMode = true;

      private static final Pattern imgRegExp = Pattern.compile("<img[^>]+src\\s*=\\s*['\"]([^'\"]+)['\"][^>]*>");

      public Email(){
            this.subject = "";
            this.sendTo = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.ccList = new ArrayList<String>();
            this.bccList = new ArrayList<String>();
      }

      public String getSendTo(){
        if(this.isDebugMode()){
          System.out.println("getSendTo() : " + this.sendTo.toString());
        }
        return this.sendTo.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
      }

      public void setSendTo(final String sendTo){
        this.sendTo.add(sendTo);
      }

      public String getCcList(){
        if(this.isDebugMode()){
          System.out.println("getCcList() : " + this.ccList.toString());
        }
        return this.ccList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
      }

      public void setCcList(final String ccList){
        this.ccList.add(ccList);
      }

      public String getBccList(){
        if(this.isDebugMode()){
          System.out.println("getBccList() : " + this.bccList.toString());
        }
        return this.bccList.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", "");
      }

      public void setBccList(final String bccList){
        this.bccList.add(bccList);
      }

      public String getSenderEmail(){
        return this.senderEmail;
      }

      public void setSenderEmail(final String senderEmail){
        this.senderEmail = senderEmail;
      }

      public String getSenderName(){
        return this.senderName;
      }

      public void setSenderName(final String senderName){
        this.senderName = senderName;
      }

      public String getSubject(){
        return this.subject;
      }

      public void setSubject(final String subject){
        this.subject = subject;
      }

      public boolean isDebugMode(){
        return this.debugMode;
      }

      public void setDebugMode(final boolean debugMode){
        this.debugMode = debugMode;
      }

      private Session getCurrentSession(){
        NotesContext nc = NotesContext.getCurrentUnchecked();
          return (null != nc) ? nc.getCurrentSession() : null;
      }

      private Database getCurrentDatabase(){
        NotesContext nc = NotesContext.getCurrentUnchecked();
          return (null != nc) ? nc.getCurrentDatabase() : null;
      }

      public void send() throws NotesException, IOException, Exception {
            Session session = getCurrentSession();
            Database database = getCurrentDatabase();
            if (null != session && null != database &&
                null != this.sendTo && null != this.subject &&
                null != this.senderEmail
            ) {
                try {
                    if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                        System.out.println("Started send()");
                    }
                    session.setConvertMime(false);
                    Document emailDocument = database.createDocument();

                    MIMEEntity emailRoot = emailDocument.createMIMEEntity("Body");
                    if (null != emailRoot) {
                        MIMEHeader emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Reply-To");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSenderEmail());

                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Return-Path");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSenderEmail());

                        final String fromSender = (null == this.getSenderName()) ?
                            this.getSenderEmail() :
                            "\"" + this.getSenderName() + "\" <" + this.getSenderEmail() + ">";

                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("From");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(fromSender);

                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Sender");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(fromSender);

                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("To");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSendTo());

                        if (!this.ccList.isEmpty()) {
                            emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("CC");
                            emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getCcList());
                        }

                        if (!this.bccList.isEmpty()) {
                            emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("BCC");
                            emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getBccList());
                        }

                        emailHeader = emailRoot.createHeader("Subject");
                        emailHeader.setHeaderVal(this.getSubject());

                        MIMEEntity emailRootChild = emailRoot.createChildEntity();
                        if (null != emailRootChild) {
                            final String boundary = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + "ABC";
                            emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-Type");
                            emailHeader.setHeaderVal("multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"");

                            MIMEEntity emailChild = emailRootChild.createChildEntity();
                            if (null != emailChild) {

                                Stream stream = session.createStream();                             

                                emailChild = emailRootChild.createChildEntity();
                                stream = session.createStream();
                                stream.writeText(this.getHTML());
                                emailChild.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"", MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
                                stream.close();
                                stream.recycle();
                                stream = null;
                            }                   
                        }
                    }
                    emailDocument.send();
                    session.setConvertMime(true);
                    if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                        System.out.println("Completed send()");
                    }
                } catch (NotesException e) {
                    if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                        System.out.println("Failed send() with NotesException" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    throw e;
                }  catch (Exception e) {
                    if (this.isDebugMode()) {
                        System.out.println("Failed send() with Exception" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }

      public String getFieldName(){
        return this.fieldName;
      }

      public void setFieldName(final String fieldName){
        this.fieldName = fieldName;
      }

      public String getHTML(){
        StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();
        html.append(getBannerHTML());
        html.append(getBodyHTML());
        html.append(getFooterHTML());
        return html.toString();
      }

      public String getBannerHTML(){
        return this.bannerHTML;
      }

      public void setBannerHTML(final String bannerHTML){
        this.bannerHTML = bannerHTML;
      }

      public String getFooterHTML(){
        return this.footerHTML;
      }

      public String getBodyHTML() {
        return bodyHTML;
    }

    public void setBodyHTML(String bodyHTML) {
        this.bodyHTML = bodyHTML;
    }

    public void setFooterHTML(final String footerHTML){
        this.footerHTML = footerHTML;
    }      

}
```

Then from your other class add something like this:

```
private void sendMail(String msg){
        try{            
            Email email = new Email();          
            email.setSendTo("yourname@acme.org");
            email.setSubject("Mail from Java");         
            email.setSenderEmail("no-rely@acme.org");           
            email.setSenderName("No-reply");            
            email.setBodyHTML(msg);             
            email.setBannerHTML("<p>Hi " + email.getSendTo() + ",</p>");            
            email.setFooterHTML("<p><b>Kind regards,</b><br/>" + email.getSenderName() + "<br/>0044 1234 5678</p>");
            email.send();           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            OpenLogUtil.logError(e);
        }
    }
```

The DominoDocument is not being read from any more. I added a field: private String bodyHTML . The setBodyHTML method I have altered into a standard setter method.

The send() method I stripped down, mainly this part:

```
MIMEEntity emailRootChild = emailRoot.createChildEntity();
                        if (null != emailRootChild) {
                            final String boundary = System.currentTimeMillis() + "-" + "ABC";
                            emailHeader = emailRootChild.createHeader("Content-Type");
                            emailHeader.setHeaderVal("multipart/alternative; boundary=\"" + boundary + "\"");

                            MIMEEntity emailChild = emailRootChild.createChildEntity();
                            if (null != emailChild) {

                                Stream stream = session.createStream();                             

                                emailChild = emailRootChild.createChildEntity();
                                stream = session.createStream();
                                stream.writeText(this.getHTML());
                                emailChild.setContentFromText(stream, "text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"", MIMEEntity.ENC_NONE);
                                stream.close();
                                stream.recycle();
                                stream = null;
                            }                   
                        }
```

In the end you get just a basic HTML email, without images or attachments. I am not sure if this fits your needs?

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I used your code and I am able to send emails now!

Answer (score 2):

The way to send mail in Domino is via a Document. The easiest way is to create one in `mail.box`, the router database. There you can save only once and saving will send off the message.

However....
Tony’s class should work just fine without any conversion work you mentioned. A managed bean is just a simple Java class with an argument free constructor and get/set methods.

So from other Java code you should be able to just use this:

```
EmailBean email = new EmailBean();
email.set(...) // to, body, subject etc
email.send();
```

What you need to change:

- `get/setHTMLBody` needs to work like HTMLfooter -> store in a local variable
- add a `get/setTextBody` method and local variable
- in the `send()` method instead of extracting from document, use the local variables

Does that work for you?

Comment: You mean via a Document (and not a DominoDocument)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same conversion process for OpenNTF Domino API. It has a `DominoEmail` class, see https://stash.openntf.org/projects/ODA/repos/dominoapi/browse/domino/core/src/org/openntf/domino/email?at=30690a2ddccb024bae6fcf37cbdd42860c7e5ba6. This works for basic emails, including HTML I believe. But it's not complete for supporting e.g. attachments. I'm happy for someone to be able to complete that aspect, if there's a specific need and happy to offer advice to help progress.